# How to move a multilayer image with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, move, alpha-transparency

This is an ImageMagick question. I am trying to move all pixels of an image using:

```
convert -page +X+Y old.png -background none new.png
```

only old.png contains a few layers of opaque, transparent and semi-transparent information and therefore (here my "therefore" is empirical, I do not really understand the phenomenon) nothing moves. If I flatten everything out and try:

```
convert -page +X+Y old.png -background none -flatten new.png
```

then the opaque part moves, but the transparent and semi-transparent information gets lots. I can see that by applying

```
convert new.png -alpha off new_alpha_off.png
```

and observing only the opaque pixels in new_alpha_off.png.

So here is my question: how to move an image with all its layers, without loosing the transparent, or at least semi-transparent pixels?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion for the command?

Answer (score 0):

Running this command

```
convert                      \
   img-with-transparency.png \
  -page +30+60               \
  -background none           \
  -flatten                   \
   output.png
```

works perfectly as can be seen from this example:

[image: img-with-transparency.png] `=>` [image: output.png]

(Both images still have transparent background).

My ImageMagick version is this:

```
convert -version
   Version: ImageMagick 6.7.9-0 2012-09-09 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
   Features:  OpenCL HDRI
```

Which version is yours?